# Why does my Jenkins httpRequest plugin have no content?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, httprequest

I'm trying to send an httpRequest to an agent, to determine if it's online.  The code from my pipeline looks like this.

```
@NonCPS
def isNodeOffline() {
    def response = httpRequest url: "http://jenkinsServer/computer/NodeName/api/json"
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content)
    return json.offline
}
```

From the stage, I'm calling the function, and printing the results.

```
def nodeOffline = isNodeOffline()
println("NodeOffline: "+nodeOffline)
```

However, when I run this code, the result is

`NodeOffline: Status: 200`

For some reason, the httpRequest is only returning the status.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the @NonCPS annotation.  You can't call steps (httpRequest) in non-cps methods. Have a look at the docs on CPS - https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps

Comment: I still don't understand why it works, but removing @NonCPS does work.

Comment: Someplace in the documentation it says that non-CPS methods can not call pipeline steps (like httpRequest). Unfortunately, it doesn’t throw an exception when you do this, it just doesn’t work.